# Join multiple tables, including one table twice, and sort by counting a group

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I am an amateur just trying to finish his last question of his assignment (it is past due at this point, just looking for understanding) I sat and shot attempts at this for almost 5 hours now across two days, and have had no success.

I have tried looking through all the different types of joins, couldn't get grouping to work (ever) and have had little luck with the sorting as well. I can do all of these things one at a time, but the difficulty here was getting all of these things to work in union.

This is the question:

> Write a SQL query to retrieve a list that has (source city, source code, destination city, 
>   destination code, and number-of-flights) for all source-dest pairs with at least 2 flights. Order 
>   by the number_of_flights. Note that the “dest”, and “source” attributes in the “flights” table 
>   are both referenced to the “airportid” in the “airports” table.

Here are the tables I have to work with (also came with about 3000 lines of dummy entries)

```
create table airports (
    airportid char(3)       primary key, 
    city varchar(20)
);
create table airlines (
    airlineid char(2)       primary key, 
    name varchar(20), 
    hub char(3)             references airports(airportid)
); 
create table customers (
    customerid char(10)     primary key, 
    name varchar(25), 
    birthdate date, 
    frequentflieron char(2) references airlines(airlineid)
);
create table flights (
    flightid char(6)        primary key, 
    source char(3)          references airports(airportid), 
    dest char(3)            references airports(airportid), 
    airlineid char(2)       references airlines(airlineid), 
    local_departing_time date, 
    local_arrival_time date
);
create table flown (
    flightid char(6)        references flights(flightid), 
    customerid char(10)     references customers, 
    flightdate date
);
```

The first problem I ran in to was outputting airports.city twice in the same query but with different results. Not only that, but no matter what I tried when grouping I would always get the same result:

> Not a GROUP BY expression

Normally I have fun trying to piece these together, but this has been frustrating. Help!

Comment: note you should tag this as homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select source.airportid as source_airportid,
       source.city source_city,
       dest.airportid as dest_airportid,
       dest.city as dest_city,
       count(*) as flights
from   flights
inner join airports source on source.airportid = flights.source
inner join airports dest on dest.airportid = flights.dest
group by
       source.airportid,
       source.city,
       dest.airportid,
       dest.city
having count(*) >= 2
order by 5;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. I'll be studying this so I fully understand it, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The subquery approach by ericb below is more optimized and would perform faster and consume less database resources (cpu, memory etc.) when the flights table is much larger than the airports table.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a subquery?

```
SELECT  source_airports.city, 
        source_airports.airportid,
        dest_airports.city,
        dest_airports.airportid,
        x.number_of_flights
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  source, dest, COUNT(*) as number_of_flights
        FROM    flights 
        GROUP BY source, dest
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) as x
    INNER JOIN airports as dest_airports
    ON dest_airports.airportid = x.dest
    INNER JOIN airports as source_airports
    ON source_airports.airportid = x.source
ORDER BY x.number_of_flights ASC
```

Comment: +1 I like the subquery approach because it limits the GROUP BY clause to those things you are counting (specifically, source-destination pairs).

Comment: I actually did try constructing a few sub queries myself but didn't fully understand them, and thus never got it working. Thanks for your post!

Comment: @ScottC if this is homework, you should look at why a subquery might be a better option in this instance than performing all the joins first. The subquery will limit the records before the join happens, making it a potentially less expensive query.

Comment: I like the idea of a less expensive query, but don't fully understand how you did what you did. I'll have to read more in to sub queries